# Using global Rails-UJS in TS modules (Rails with webpacker)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker, ts-loader, rails-ujs

I'm trying to use `Rails` from `@rails/ujs` in `webpacker` `ts-loader` similar to `Rails` in the asset pipeline. I want a global variable `Rails` available in all modules.

For now, I can circumvent the problem by importing it in each module, but, *for the sake of addressing the problem*, how can we make a global module that `ts-loader` won't cry about.

Firstly, I already have jquery configured as `$`. I don't see why `@rails/ujs` as `Rails` isn't working similarly. Here is my (simplified) configuration:

```
// tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "lib": ["dom", "es2020"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": ["**/*.spec.ts", "node_modules", "vendor", "public"]
  ...
}
```

```js
// config/webpack/loaders/typescript.js
...
module.exports = {
  rules: [
    {
      ...
      loader: 'ts-loader',
      options: { transpileOnly: true },
    },
    ...
  ],
  resolve: { plugins: ... },
}
```

```js
// config/webpack/environment.js

...

// Globals
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  Rails: ['@rails/ujs'], /* also tried Rails: '@rails/ujs', */
}))
...
```

```
// app/.../packs/application/index.ts
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()

import './rails-inquirer'

// app/.../packs/application/rails-inquirer/index.ts
console.log(Rails)
```

```sh
$ bin/webpack --display errors-only
TS2304: Cannot find name 'Rails'
```

Related: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56128114/using-rails-ujs-in-js-modules-rails-6-with-webpacker) similar question is not a duplicate of my problem. That question does not address Typescript. Neither does its answer which I followed. It did, however, fix my `eslint`. I'm thinking this is a `ts-loader` config problem.

Comment: The only difference I see between jquery and Rails-UJS is jquery is simply used, but `@rails/ujs` has a `require("@rails/ujs").start()` line in the top module.

Comment: Did you end up finding a way to resolve this, @RWDJ?

Comment: @s_dolan I did not. I ended up doing imports.