# Submit simple form remotely on the basis of a click event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, simple-form

I am trying to create a todo app in which the checkbox is created using the simple form and this needs to be submitted remotely when the checkbox is clicked. I am using the onchange() function but the form isnt getting submitted remotely. It is submitting via a full page refresh.

When a submit button is included, it submits the form remotely and everything works fine. But i am not able to get it to work without the submit button but only using the check box.

_goal.html.erb

```
<li id='<%= "Goal_li_#{goal.id}" %>'>
  <div class="collapsible-header"  tabindex="0">
    <label>
      <%= simple_form_for(goal, url:goal_path(goal),remote: true,authenticity_token: true) do |f| %>
        <%= f.check_box :is_complete,onchange: 'this.form.submit();', disabled:goal_disabled_class(goal), class: "check_box_check" %>
        <span class=<%= "line-through-goal" if goal.is_complete==1 %>>
          <%= goal.title %>-<%= goal.id %>-<%= goal.status %>
        </span>

        <%= "<span class='new badge blue right'> #{goal.sub_goals.where(is_complete: 0).count} </span>".html_safe if goal.sub_goals.where(is_complete: 0).count > 0  %>
      <% end %>
    </label>
  </div>
</li>
```

This is leading to a page refresh instead of submitting the form remotely. All the examples i have found to be working are using the submit button. How can i trigger the remote execution on the basis of checkbox click?

Answer (score 0):

Because of `rails-ujs` it is submitted via normal HTML request. Related [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29546#issue-238135942) and [answer](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29546#issuecomment-313572043).

Try this way:

```
onchange: 'Rails.fire(this.form, "submit")'
```

Comment: On changing this, i am getting JS exception that Rails is not defined. 
I have tried these but still i am getting same error : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56128114/using-rails-ujs-in-js-modules-rails-6-with-webpacker