# Rails 6 webpack throwing 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

Hi i recently started working on Rails 6 with ruby 2.6.5. as the rails 6 has introduced the webpacks so i am trying to load my js files with the webpack. Although i have already required the jquery in the appliation.js still i am getting the below error:

```
'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined'
```

application.js

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require('packs/jquery')
```

My 'jquery.js' file is inside the packs directory. Please let me know if i am missing something. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is `jQuery` defined? `$` is an alias for `jQuery` object so long as `noConflict()` hasn't been used

Comment: i found a way window.$ = window.jQuery = require('packs/jquery') this is working but now i have another similar problem i am using masonry.pkgd.min.js now i am getting  masonry is not defined. do you have any clue how to define it?

Comment: You should check it at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58161486/4631412

Answer (score 17):

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
  jquery: 'jquery',
  'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
  Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}))

module.exports = environment
```

In `config/webpack/environment.js` and delete `require('packs/jquery')` in `application.js`