# Rails 6: Rails not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-ujs

I am trying to fire a form submit using UJS:

```
  <%= f.file_field :profile_image,
                   direct_upload: true,
                   accept: 'image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg',
                   onchange: "Rails.fire(this.form, 'submit')"
  %>
```

However, I see the following error in the JS console:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Rails
```

The application layout file points to the application JS pack:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

And I can see that it loads by the output of console log:

```
console.log('Application pack loaded')
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
```

From what I understand, rails ujs should expose the `Rails` object. Is that right?

Why isn't the `Rails` variable available to the browser? What do I need to do to ensure it is?

Comment: Please check link, https://stackoverflow.com/a/58161486/4631412
Maybe it can helpful for you.

Answer (score 10):

I have learnt from [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/36686) raised against Rails 6.0rc1 that I need to expose the `Rails` object myself. I wrongly assumed that it would work out of the box. Perhaps it did when Rails used the asset pipeline.

I am able to access the `Rails` object by adding this to my pack:

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs";
window.Rails = Rails;
```

Comment: Thank you, it fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I also needed to do `Rails.start()` in Rails 7 but this worked for me. Thank you!